# Typeclass instance not found for generic

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming, typeclass

I can't get GHC to resolve the generic typeclass instance below: (The goal is to achieve the same effect as accessing the property `x` of `point` like `x point`, but, instead by utilizing type level strings)

```
data Label (l :: Symbol) =
  Get

class Has a l b | a l -> b where
  get :: a -> Label l -> b

instance (Generic r, GenericHas (Rep r) pl pt) => Has r pl pt where
  get = genericHas . from

class GenericHas a l b | a l -> b where
  genericHas :: a x -> Label l -> b

instance GenericHas (D1 a (C1 b (S1 (c ('Just pl) d e f) (Rec0 pt)))) pl pt where
  genericHas (M1 (M1 (M1 (K1 v)))) _ = v

data Point =
  Point
    { x :: Int
    }
  deriving (Show, Generic)

example :: Int
example = get (Point 1) (Get :: Label "x")
```

This below is the error:

```
    * No instance for (GenericHas
                         (D1
                            ('MetaData
                               "Point"
                               "Alba.Persistence"
                               "alba-0.1.0.0-w6KgEimatKAP1g0rWS7YT"
                               'False)
                            (C1
                               ('MetaCons "Point" 'PrefixI 'True)
                               (S1
                                  ('MetaSel
                                     ('Just "x")
                                     'NoSourceUnpackedness
                                     'NoSourceStrictness
                                     'DecidedLazy)
                                  (Rec0 Int))))
                         "x"
                         Int)
        arising from a use of `get'
    * In the expression: get (Point 1) (Get :: Label "x")
      In an equation for `example':
          example = get (Point 1) (Get :: Label "x")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that GHC is unable to match `c` with `'MetaSel`, because `'MetaSel` is of a higher kind. By default fresh type variables are assumed to have kind `*`, so the matching fails here.

One way to fix this is to just replace `c` with `'MetaSel`:

```
instance GenericHas (D1 a (C1 b (S1 (`MetaSel ('Just pl) d e f) (Rec0 pt)))) pl pt where
```

Another way is to enable `PolyKinds`. This will tell GHC *not* to assume kind `*` for fresh variables and the matching will succeed.

---

Bonus: you can have a nicer syntax with `TypeApplications`. You can write `Get @"x"` instead of `Get :: Label "x"`. Or you can go even further and define a function that wraps the `Get`:

```
get' :: forall (l :: Symbol) a b. Has a l b => a -> b
get' a = get a (Get @l)

-- Usage:
example = get' @"x" (Point 1)
```

Comment: Can you use PolyKinds somehow to indicate a properly polymorphic kind for `c`?

Comment: @Carl you're absolutely right, I haven't thought about that at all! I'm used to have `PolyKinds` always enabled, so didn't even occur to me. I'll update the answer.